# How can I host a simple WCF as a windows service in 2008?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a (very) simple WCF written in VB which I can build and publish locally to IIS. Works great.

What I need to do is (somehow) deploy it to a different server which does not have IIS. It's supposed to be run as a windows service.

I have no idea how to do this. All directions on MSDN seem to be for VS 2010 (we're using 2008).

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the MSDN docs

[How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

It definitely has a version for .NET framework 3.5 / VS 2008, and samples in VB.NET.

OR watch this screencast by Aaron Skonnard on [Self-Hosting WCF Services](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Self-hosting-WCF-Services) - 10 minutes well spent !!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm running VS2008 so the video is quite useless. I've been through the docs, and unfortunately they are written for C (I'm using VB), a futile effort. The MSDN shows some VB code, but the entire article was written for C. Anyone know of a straight-forward example using Visual Studio 2008 with VB.NET?

Comment: @Jason: self-hosting really isn't much different between .NET 3.5/VS2008 and the newer versions ....

Comment: This link did the trick: http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/

Comment: @user724198 broken link now